# How declare tagged union of polymorphic collection types

Tags: purescript

I'm new to Purescript.  My current learning exercise is to create a tagged union of polymorphic Array and List.  I'll use it in a function that finds the length of any Array or List. Here's my attempt:

```
import Data.List as L
import Data.Array as A

data Collection = CollectionList (forall a. L.List a) 
                | CollectionArray (forall b.  Array b)

colLength :: Collection -> Int
colLength (CollectionList list) = L.length list
colLength (CollectionArray arr) = A.length arr

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
   logShow (colLength (CollectionArray [3,5]))
```

The compiler doesn't like it:

```
 Could not match type Int with type b0     

 while checking that type Int is at least as general as type b0
 while checking that expression 3 has type b0
 in value declaration main

 where b0 is a rigid type variable
```

I'm confused by the parts, `checking that type Int is at least as general as type b0` and `b0 is a rigid type variable`.  My intention was to allow `b` to be anything.  Not sure what I did to make the compiler put conditions on what `b` can be.

If you know how, please show the correct way to define a tagged union of polymoric types that'll work in my `colLength` function.

Comment: You could look up "existential types" that can express "for some type a we have a list of a". However, that's not a good idea: after such a list is constructed, there will be no meaningful way to access the list of unknown types beyond computing its length. So, you could directly store the length and avoid the existential type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forall a` doesn't mean "any type goes here"

It means that whoever *accesses* the value, gets to choose what `a` is, and whoever *provides* the value has to make sure that the value is of that type. It's a contract between the provider and the consumer.

So when you provide the value `CollectionArray [3,5]`, you have to make it such that it works *for all* possible `a` that whoever accesses that value later might choose.

Obviously, there is only one way you can construct such value:

```
CollectionArray []
```

---

What you probably *actually* meant to do (and I'm guessing here) was to make your collection polymorphic, in the sense that it can contain values of any type, but the type is chosen by whoever *creates* the collection, and then whoever accesses it later has to deal with that particular type.

To do that, you have to put the type variable on the outside:

```
data Collection a = CollectionList (L.List a) 
                  | CollectionArray (Array a)
```

That way, when you create a collection `CollectionArray [3,5]`, it becomes of type `Collection Int`, and now everywhere you pass it, such as `colLength`, will have to deal with that `Int`

This, in turn, can be achieved by making `colLength` itself generic:

```
colLength :: forall a. Collection a -> Int
colLength (CollectionList list) = L.length list
colLength (CollectionArray arr) = A.length arr
```

Now whoever accesses (i.e. calls) `colLength` itself gets to choose what `a` is, which works fine, because it's the same place that created the `Connection Int` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the double dose of help, on polymorphic collections and making the function generic.  I need to meditate on it to fully grok it.

Comment: Hi Fyodor, you mentioned that in `data Collection = CollectionList (forall a. L.List a) | CollectionArray (forall b.  Array b)`, `forall a` doesn't mean "any type goes here". And that "whoever accesses it gets to gets to choose what `a` is". Two questions: 1) What constraint did I accidentally put on `a` and `b`, that made the compiler not accept `CollectionArray [3,5]`? 2) Are there any realistic situations where my original `data` definition could be useful? Thanks again.

Comment: To the second question the answer is "no". The first question, I already answered.